# How do I add value of "-" to pillar?

Tags: yaml, salt-stack

I have pillar that is supposed to have value of "-" (without the quotation).

I tried:

```
my_pillar: -
my_pillar: '-'
my_pillar: "-"
my_pillar: {% raw %}"-"{% endraw %}
{% raw %}my_pillar: "-"{% endraw %}
```

None of those worked and I am getting error: "block sequence entries are not allowed in this context".
I understand what the problem here is, Salt thinks that it is part of YAML definition of values, not the value itself, but how do I work around that?

Comment: All except the first one will work. Are you sure you didn't just have a caching issue?

Answer (score 0):

As OrangeDog mentions, any type of quoting will work:

```
docker run --rm -it saltstack/salt /bin/sh
mkdir -p /srv/pillar
cat <<EOF>/srv/pillar/top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - stuff
EOF
echo "my_pillar: -" >/srv/pillar/stuff.sls
salt-call --local pillar.items -ldebug
# Error happens ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
echo "my_pillar: '-'" >/srv/pillar/stuff.sls
salt-call pillar.items
```

The output for me:

```
local:
    ----------
    my_pillar:
        -
```